# null value in ViewModel

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I has a ViewModel (StoreViewModel). When I get value in VM from View to Controller (Post), some value is null, only some value that is shown on View is not null

Plz help me

```
    public class StoreViewModel
    {
        public StoreViewModel() { }
        public Store Store { get; set; }
        public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public List<AccountPayable> AccountsPayable { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my View

```
    <% using(Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <div><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Store.Name) %></div>
    <div><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Store.State) %></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    <% } %>
```

I set [HiddenInput (DisplayValue = false)] on columns in Entity Store, Member, Order, AccountPayable

+++

Here is my Controller. (I tried  use FormCollection to get value from View, but...unsuccess)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Details(Finger finger, StoreViewModel storeVM)
        {
            //if (finger.roleName != "Administrator")
            //    return RedirectToAction("DisplayNotice", "Notice");
            storeVM.Store.Active = (CheckBoxHelpers.GetValue(storeVM.Store.Active)).ToString();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {               
                storesRep.SaveStore(storeVM.Store, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(storeVM);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("List", "Stores");
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us your controller code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the value is actually present in the POST request. The fact that your are getting `null` is a strong indication that this is not the case. You could use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see exactly what values are posted to the server.

Also from what I can see your form contains only store name and state text fields so those are the only values you can expect to get back in your POST action:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <div><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Store.Name) %></div>
    <div><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Store.State) %></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
<% } %>
```

You might need to include the others as well. You could use hidden fields to send the values you need.

In your controller action you are trying to read the `storeVM.Store.Active` field so include 
it in your form:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.Store.Active) %>
```